# reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that void conforms to T

Tags: java, unit-testing, compiler-errors, mockito, aws-java-sdk

I want to do nothing when cloudWatchRuleDestroy.destroy(@NonNull String ruleName) function of another class is called.

I have tried Mock and InjectMocks but "cloudWatchRuleDestroyer.destroy(any())" makes the compiler show "reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that void conforms to T"

```
    public void testHandleRequest() {
        doNothing().when(cloudWatchRuleDestroyer.destroy(any()));
        handler.handleRequest(inputMap);
    }
```

How to avoid this compiler error? What is the change I need to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax of brackets is wrong.

Correct Syntax:

```
doReturn(someObject)
    .when(someInstance)
    .someMethod();
```